# Match word within a range, match 2nd word within a range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

First of all. This forum is great. I have used it a lot and didn't had the need to create my own question. Until now.

I have a datasheet with a free text field in column O.
I filtered out the most occurring words and summed them up in sheet1.
I created column P with a match function to identify the most occurring word in the free text field.
I used the following formula in column P. It works for finding the first most occurring word.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$794;MATCH(1;COUNTIF(O8;"*"&Sheet1!$B$2:$B$794&"*");0));"")
```

(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$794 contains the words that are searched for)
Until now, everything works fine.

I want to add another formula in column Q to find the second most occurring word. I.e. It should search for the first matching word it finds in sheet one, but cannot be the word that has already been found.

I tried tweaking the formula a bit to add another criteria using COUNTIFS, but i cant make it work. 
I tried this formula: (in column Q)

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$794;MATCH(1;COUNTIFS(O8;"*"&Sheet1!$B$2:$B$794&"*";`**`O8;<>"*"&P8&"*")`**`;0));"")`

The bold part is not working.

Any suggestions to fix it?

Also, is there a way to post an example excel sheet?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

This is the output that I am looking for.
[Excel example required output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0FFU.png)

It searches words from a predefined set of words as suchs:
[Excel example search words](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BB2O7.png)

So in this example I analysed how many times each word occurs in column I "Commentaar". Apparently the word 'en' occurs 3 times, the word 'pauze' 2 times, etc. I delete some of the words that I am not interested in such as 'EN'. The remaining list is a set of words that I want to search for. 
So in cel P8, it should return the first word on the list that matches with any of the words in the free text field I8. The first matchingword on the list it finds is Pauze, hence cell P8 returns 'Pauze', the second matching word is 'Simulatie', hence Q8 returns Simulatie.

I hope that this makes it a bit more clear

Comment: Can you mock up some data and expected output?

Comment: you were very close to the first formula =)

Answer (score 0):

If one has the new Dynamic Array formulas available in Office 365 Subscription:

```
=TRANSPOSE(MID(SORT(UNIQUE(TEXT(COUNTIF(A1:A12,A1:A12),"0000")&"-"&A1:A12),,-1),6,9999))
```

Excel will spill the results to the right.

[image]

---

Without the Dynamic Array formula we can use:

```
=INDEX(INDEX($A$1:$A$13,N(IF({1},MODE.MULT(IF(MATCH($A$1:$A$13,$A:$A)=ROW($A$1:$A$13),ROW($A$1:$A$13)*{1,1}))))),COLUMN(A1))
```

Put that in column P. Then confirm with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  Then copy/Drag over and it will pick up the first then the second then the third.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Scott. The output is close to what I desire. I added an example in the OP because my data is a bit different. Also, correct me if I am wrong but your formula seems to search for an exact match within the same column. My data doesn't have that. The data is a free text field where people can enter whatever they want, so basically every output is unique. I added an example in the OP for clarification. Any idea's on how to work with that?

Answer (score 0):

This should work with all versions of Excel. This assumes data are in column `A` for simplicity.

The following array formula must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter...

```
=INDEX(A1:A9,MATCH(LARGE(COUNTIF(A1:A9,A1:A9),MAX(COUNTIF(A1:A9,A1:A9))+1),COUNTIF(A1:A9,A1:A9),))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this and if I understand correctly, it searches for exact matches. My data is not an exact match to the search value. Also, your suggestion only searches for the most occuring match. I am particularly interested in the second most occuring match. I added an example in the OP for clarification.

Comment: Your question now presents a completely different scenario that you originally asked. My solution was a perfect answer to your original question. You should select one of these answers and ask a new question. People volunteered their time to help you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, this is probably what you want!

Although you said that `finding the first most occurring word` but I think you're trying to find the nearest match [top -> down] after looking at the expression you give.

Here is the formula:

```
D2=IfError(INDEX($B$2:$B$12,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$12)/COUNTIF($D$1,"*"&$B$2:$B$12&"*"),ROW(A1))),"")
```

Office365:

```
F2=FILTER(B2:B12,COUNTIF(D1,"*"&B2:B12&"*"))
```

[image]

how it works:

- `ROW($1:$12)/COUNTIF($D$1,"*"&$B$2:$B$12&"*")` return array index row
  if match.
- Aggregate ignore error and return index row ascending with `row(A1)`

I hope I understand it correctly :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. You are right, it is about finding the nearest match. I added an example in the OP. My required output is a bit different compared to the solution that you propose.

Comment: Post another question and describe it briefly and exactly what you want!